# How to remove an array from a json object with python?

Tags: python, json

This is the content of my json file:

```
{
  "tabID": [
    {
      "dat": [1, "q"],
      "opt": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm building a python app that process that json file and I need to remove `"opt":[]`.

I've tried next code:

```
data['tabID'][0].remove('data')
```

But it doesn't work.

Could you give me any advice? Thanks.

Comment: You can use *del* statement: `del data['tabID'][0]['opt']`.

Comment: For things this simple, post running code so we can just copy/paste for experimenting. Your json has a bug and we have to write the surrounding code to test an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a dict and pop the key.

Fixed an error in your JSON. Working example is at https://repl.it/repls/FrighteningPungentEquipment or as actual code:

```py
import json

the_json_string = '{"tabID":[{"dat":[1, "q"],"opt":[] }]}'

obj = json.loads(the_json_string)
obj['tabID'][0].pop('opt')

print(json.dumps(obj))
```

Comment: The json string could be in triple quotes for readability `"""{"tabID":[{"dat":[1, "q"],"opt":[] }]}""". And just delete your first attempt since it doesn't really help people in the future.

Comment: @tdelaney, [raw prefix](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) or single quotes could be even better.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - Potentially, yes. I was thinking in terms of keeping the line breaks in the original example. Raw strings are great if you want embedded "\n" in the json too.